# Why do I get error 1054 using trigger on INSERT saying that column isn't on the field list?

Tags: mysql, trigger

I am trying to write a Trigger to register every new inserted genre into a *news* table.

[Here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7640464/) are the tables definitions. They are only two, `GENEROS` & `NOVEDADES`.

This is the trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER insertarNovedades AFTER INSERT ON GENEROS
FOR EACH ROW 
    INSERT INTO NOVEDADES (novedad) VALUES (CONCAT('Nuevo genero: ', genero));
$$
```

But MySQL don't let me use it:

```
mysql> INSERT INTO GENEROS (genero)VALUES('f');
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'genero' in 'field list'
```

What is wrong on the trigger code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works:

```
CREATE TRIGGER insertarNovedades AFTER INSERT ON GENEROS
FOR EACH ROW
    INSERT INTO NOVEDADES (novedad) VALUES (CONCAT('Nuevo genero: ', new.genero));
```

---

[Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html) has this example and the following explanation:

```
mysql> CREATE TRIGGER ins_sum BEFORE INSERT ON account
     -> FOR EACH ROW SET @sum = @sum + NEW.amount; Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.06 sec)
```

> The statement following FOR EACH ROW defines the trigger body; that is, the statement to execute each time the trigger activates, which occurs once for each row affected by the triggering event. In the example, the trigger body is a simple SET that accumulates into a user variable the values inserted into the amount column. The statement refers to the column as NEW.amount which means “the value of the amount column to be inserted into the new row.”

Comment: I would like to know why the hell is necessary to use `NEW` when is the only choice? That should be the default, no need for write it *explicitly*.

Comment: @Lucio Explicit is better than implicit. `NEW` may not always be the only choice. You may have `INSERT ... SELECT ... FROM` there or `UPDATE ... FROM`, with possibly more than one tables in the `FROM` clause. Then there may be a `genero` column in multiple tables besides the `NEW` (pseudo-table).

Comment: @ypercube Sorry, I missed that part. I'm not sure, but are you saying something like this? `TRIGGER...INSERT...FOR EACH ROW INSERT INTO GENEROS (genero) VALUES(NEW.genero)` If that is possible, then yeah, the NEW keyword would be necessary.

Comment: There are also UPDATE triggers where there would be both a `NEW.genero` and an `OLD.genero` column. Your suggestion would not work there.

Comment: No, I meant things like `TRIGGER...INSERT...FOR EACH ROW INSERT INTO novedades (..columns..) SELECT ... FROM another_table_or_tables ;`

Comment: The update trigger is another case. Now I understand your point with that example. Thanks, point taken.